# How do I upload a large Audio file longer than 30sec direct from the browser to AwS S3?

Tags: audio, xmlhttprequest

I would like to save audio recording to S3. I am using the functions below to load direct to awsS3  direct from the browser. It works for short audio recordings of up to around 25 seconds but fails for larger files.

Currently the functions is as follows: I speak into the microphone using recorder.js. Once the recording is complete I press stop which then saves the file to AWS

From the browser:

```
getSignedRequest(file,fileLoc);





    function getFetchSignedRequest(file,fileLoc){
const fetchUrl = `/xxxxxxxxx?file-name=${file.name}&file-type=${file.type}&fileLoc=${fileLoc}`;
  fetch(fetchUrl )
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('response',response)
          if(!response.ok){
              console.log('Network response was not OK',response.ok)
          } else {
              putAudioFetchFile(file, response.signedRequest, response.url)
              }
      })
     .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Could not get signed URL:', error);
      })
  }
```

This send a get request to the NodeJs server which calls this :

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
  const fs = require('fs');
  aws.config.region = 'xxxxxx';
  const S3_BUCKET = process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET

this.uploadToAWSDrive =
async function uploadToAWSDrive(req,res){
  const s3 = new aws.S3();
  const URL_EXPIRATION_SECONDS = 3000;

  const subFolderName = req.query['fileLoc'];
  const fileName = req.query['file-name'];
  const fileType = req.query['file-type'];
  const fileLocName = subFolderName +  fileName;

const s3Params = {
      Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
      Key: fileLocName,
      Expires: URL_EXPIRATION_SECONDS,
      ContentType: fileType,
      ACL: 'public-read'
    };

    await s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params, (err, data) => {
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return res.end();
      }

      const returnData = {
        signedRequest: data,
        url: `https://${S3_BUCKET}.s3.amazonaws.com/${fileLocName}`
      };
console.log('audio uploaded',returnData)
      res.write(JSON.stringify(returnData));
      res.end();
    });
}
```

Which then calls this:

```
function uploadFile(file, signedRequest, url){
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('PUT', signedRequest);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if(xhr.readyState === 4){
      if(xhr.status === 200){
        console.log('destination url= ', url,xhr.readyState,xhr.status)
      }
      else{
        alert('Could not upload file.');
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.send(file);
}
```

This then sends the file to the awsS3 server. Ok for audio less than 30secs, but fails for longer audio files.

What do I need to do to enable this to work with audio files of greater than 20secs and upto 3 mins?

Any help most appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant but the issue was resolved by adding a timer to the origanal function call. A function that followed also needed to be delayed to I think allow processor time. I am sure there will be better ways to do this.

```
setTimeout( getSignedRequest( myAudioFile,fileLoc), proccessTime)  ;
```